# Retrieving Records Based On Field In Related Model

Tags: cakephp

I have an employees table with status that is active, new and resigned. In my drop down menu for the application i have all 3 different statuses that is active, new and resigned,now i wanna link to each different status, that is when i click on active it only shows me the active users in the employee table.

Please not status table is linked to the employees table.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
        $records = $this->Employee->find('all', array(
            'recursive' => -1,
            'joins' => array(
                array(
                'table' => 'status',
                'alias' => 'Status',
                'type' => 'INNER',
                'conditions' => 'Employee.status = Status.id'
                )
            ),
            'fields' => array('Employee.field1', 'Employee.field2'),
            'conditions' => array('Status.id' => 'your_status_id'),
        ) 
        );
```